# High availability-Odoo-server -Openstack

Tags: openstack, high-availability, odoo-9, heartbeat

I installed Openstack on my server .
Then I installed odoo9 in a virtual machine  ubuntu14.04 under Openstack.
Now I want to ensure high availability of my Odoo-server.

So I decided to install "heartbeat" !!

But I have problems with IPflottantes (Openstack) and virtual IP of the cluster.
Can you help me please, how can I configure "heartbeat".

Comment: You don't provide enough details about what problems you have with the FlaotingIP.

Comment: For Odoo: the web interface address is: "@ipflottante (given by OpenStack): 8069" .Knowing that the machines have private @.
So I do not know how to configure heartbeat or rather "haresources".

Comment: I highly suggest using docker containers instead of virtual machines.